# I am developing a custom plugin in cake PHP 2.x, But I am not able to access it using it's routes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have created plugin using it's documentation written in Cookbook.

`cake bake plugin Mytool`

And it does fine created a plugin named Mytool inside the app plugin folder.
Now created a controller using command.

`cake bake controller Tests --plugin Mytool`

It created a new controller inside the app plugin controller folder and then I created routes inside app plugin config routes.php file as

`Router::connect('/testing', array('plugin' => 'recontool', 'controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'index'));`

Then I loaded this plugin using command

`CakePlugin::load(['Recontool' => ['routes' => true]]);`

Inside the app config bootstrap.php, and plugin loaded successfully.
But when I am trying to access the routes of the plugin it does not work but only shows error of **RecontoolController could not be found.**.

I have to do this in cake PHP version 2

Comment: What URL are you trying to reach that gives this error?

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php file; you are defining wrong routes. Your Plugin name and Controller name is not proper in your route.

This should be your correct route. If your plugin name is `Mytool` and controller name is `TestsController`.

```
Router::connect('/testing', array('plugin' => 'Mytool', 'controller' => 'Tests', 'action' => 'index'));
```